# Unable to load com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

Tags: mysql, ant, testng

when I run ant for a Testng application, I am unable to load com.mysql.jdbc.Driver.

Below is the exception thrown.

```
[testng] java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
[testng] at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
[testng] at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
[testng] at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
```

Thanks and regards,
Sreekanth

Answer (score 0):

The `CLASSPATH` environment variable is **only** used by the `java.exe` command and even then only when used *without* any of the `-cp`, `-classpath`, `-jar` arguments. It is **ignored** by IDE's.

That environment variable is in real world also considered a poor practice since it breaks portability. It's only "useful" for Sun to prevent that starters get tired of typing the same classpath again and again in the `-cp` or `-classpath` arguments.  In real world, batch/shell files are preferred.

If you're using an IDE, The classpath is called the "build path" (it represents *both* compiletime and runtime classpath). You can configure it in the project's properties. You can add a complete folder, you can add individual/external JAR files, you can link projects, etcetera. Make use of it. Forget the whole `CLASSPATH` environment variable.

For command prompt,

You have to put the full path to the jarfile in the classpath (including the filename):

```
.;C:\j2sdk1.4.2_16\jre\lib;
C:\Program Files\mysql-connector-java-3.1.144\mysql-connector-java-3.1.14-bin.jar
```

As Hippo said, you have to restart `cmd` after changing that. If it doesn't work, launch your program like this:

```
java -cp ".;C:\j2sdk1.4.2_16\jre\lib;
C:\Program Files\mysql-connector-java-3.1.144\mysql-connector-java-3.1.14-bin.jar"
my.class.Name
```