# MYSQL connection fail with netbeans

Tags: mysql, connection, database-connection

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Unable to load com.mysql.jdbc.Driver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11437178/unable-to-load-com-mysql-jdbc-driver)

Hello, I am trying to update my table, but the connection keeps failing. Following is the code I have:

```
try {
            String driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
            Class.forName(driver).newInstance();
            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mysql?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull","root","P@typd79");
            Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
            String query = "INSERT INTO project_one.personal_info(ssn,name,street,city,state,zip,class,degree,s,imm) VALUES"
                    + "(" + social + "," + Name + "," + Address + "," + City + "," + State + "," + Zip
                    + "," + Year + "," + Degree + "," + HS + "," + IMM + ")";

            stmt.executeUpdate(query);
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "New student added successfully");

        } catch (Exception e) {

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Data not saved: " + e,"Error",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);

        } 

    }
```

The connection name and driver are correct, but I am getting the following error `java.lang.classnotfound.exeption:com.mysql.jdbc.Driver.`

What is it that I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're missing jdbc jar.

Answer (score 0):

You should add mysql driver jar to your build path.

Answer (score 0):

add the jdbc mysql driver from http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/